# Regular expression match a 'word' 1 character long

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to parse product names that have multiple abbreviates for sizes. For example, medium can be

```
m, medium, med
```

I tried a simple

```
preg_match('/m|medium|med/i',$prod_name,$matches);
```

which works fine for 'product m xyz'.  However, when I try 'product s/m abc' I'm getting a false-positive match. 
I also tried

```
preg_match('/\bm\b|\bmedium\b|\bmed\b/i',$prod_name,$matches);
```

to force it to be found in a word, but the m in s/m is still being matched.  I'm assuming this is due to the engine treating '/' in the name as a word delimiter?

So to sum up, I need to match 'm' in a string, but not 's/m' or 'small', etc..  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
%\b(?<![/-])(m|med|medium)(?![/-])\b%
```

You can use negative lookbehind or lookahead to exclude the offending separators. This means `"m"/"med"/"medium"` which is its own word, but not preceded or followed by a slash or a dash. It also works on the beginning and end of string, since negative lookahead/lookbehind do not force a matching character to be present.

If you only want to delimit on whitespace, you can use the positive version:

```
%\b(?<=\s|^)(m|med|medium)(?=\s|$)\b%
```

(`"m"/"med"/"medium"` which is preceded by whitespace or the start of the string, and followed by whitespace or the end of the string)

Comment: This is really only helpful if the string he is working with is not very dynamic. Regex isn't really a sustainable solution if it breaks every time a new offending character rears its ugly head

Comment: @BenRoux: Granted. I'll offer an alternative form.

Comment: Small follow-up question - I seem to be getting duplicate matches using this expression using preg_match (eg result: array([0] => med [1] => med)).  Any ideas on why? Not a really a problem - just trying to better my regex understanding.

Comment: They're not duplicate matches. You can only get one match through `preg_match`, you would get multiple matches using `preg_match_all`. The result array's first element contains the whole match; the following elements contain the capture groups, indicated by plain parentheses (i.e. not lookahead, lookbehind, no-capture...). If you run `preg_match_all` on `"m med"`, you will see a two-by-two array - matches vs. captures. In this case, I am capturing `(m|med|medium)`. If you don't need that you can use the no-capture group: `(?:m|med|medium)`, and your result should just be `Array(0 => "med")`.

Answer (score 1):

I always think of these things in ERE first.  And according to [re_format(7)](http://www.FreeBSD.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=re_format) ERE's word boundaries, `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` match the null string at the beginning and end of a word respectively.  So ... since preg should understand ERE notation, I might go with:

```
/[[:<:]](m(ed(ium)?)?)[[:>:]]/
```

Or for easier reading, perhaps:

```
/[[:<:]](m|med|medium)[[:>:]]/
```

In PHP though, you can use PREG instead of ERE.  In PREG, `\b` indicates a word boundary, so:

```
preg_match('/\b(m(ed(ium)?)?)\b/', $prod_name, $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should match `medium`, `med`, and `m`.

```
medium|med|^m$
```

Comment: This will only match `"m"` (the letter m alone in the string), but not `"shirt m male"`.

Comment: @AhmedJolani: That would match strings that begin with `medium`, strings that contain `med`, and strings that end with `m`.